# Generate javascript object name by appending string to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am getting a Javascript object `req.files` . This object can have multiple files under it. `req.files` is an `object` **and not an** `array`.

So of if user adds three files, the object will look like:

```
req.files.file0
req.files.file1
req.files.file2
```

where `file0, file1` etc is another object.

User can add upto 15 files. How can I check loop over such objects & read information from req.files.fileX ? I need to support IE 11 & chrome.

Comment: `req.files["file" + i]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access the properties of an object by a string. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(req.files).length; i++) {
    var file = req.files['file' + i];
    if (file) {
        // use file here...
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c47pj0oo/)

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming your req object looks like this:

```
var req = {
  files: {
    file0: {},
    file1: {},
    file2: {},
    //...
    file14: {}
  }
};
```

If so, you can reference the file like this: `req.files['file0']`

So your loop could look like this:

```
for (prop in req.files) {
    var file = req.files[prop];
}
```

But you don't even need to use a loop:

```
var getReqFile = function(x){
  return req.files['file' + x] || null;
}
var file = getReqFile(5);
```